# jdbc-initialize-database can't find script files - DataAccessResourceFailureException

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry

I cannot get my Spring web app to find my scripts.  I have the jdbc namespace configured.  I have the scripts written, but, I can't figure out why no matter where I put the scripts, they can't be found. I've specifically marked folders are 'class folders'.  I've put them in the same folderr as all my jars... I've thrown a hundred rocks.  It's almost as though the error listed is not really my error.

This should be so simple, but sometimes, I just hit stumps.

Ultimately, I'm trying to get code in place so I can initialize a database I've promoted to CloudFoundry.

I get "Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [etcog-schema.sql]".  This is my code--just like every other example I've found.

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:etcog-schema.sql"/>
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:etcog-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using STS and if you have created your application using the Spring Templates, then if you just put your *.sql file(s) inside **src/main/resources**, you should be able to access them via classpath:...

Comment: Thank you... I was just fixing to come back here and say just that.  I created a folder called 'db' and changed the servlet-context entries to "<jdbc:spring location="/resources/db/my-sql-statements.sql"/>

Comment: I've left another question on a Connection link error I'm getting I would be very grateful if you could address if you have a sec...

Comment: For detail, the addScript() will call the ResourceLoader to getResource(), and this function is well-documented