# Set up H2 embedded datasource in spring application context

Tags: spring, datasource, h2

I have dataSource set up with MySQL for deployment but I want to set up a test environment with H2 database.

My application context configuration with MySQL dataSource is

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDatabase");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        dataSource.setInitialSize(2);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(10);
        return dataSource;
    }
```

I've tried doing the following to set up datasource with H2

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("devopsdistilled.operp.server.data")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("server/jdbc.properties")
@ComponentScan("server.data")
public class JpaH2TestContext {

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Value("server.data.entity")
    private String packagesToScan;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setName("MyDatabase").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        jpaVendorAdapter
                .setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());
        emf.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan);
        emf.setJpaProperties(this.hibernateProperties());
        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaDialect jpaDialect() {
        return new HibernateJpaDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory()
                .getObject());
        transactionManager.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProps = new Properties();
        hibernateProps.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        return hibernateProps;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

Only `dataSource()` is changed.
With that set up with H2 datasource, I get output in console.

```
// ... More like these

ERROR: Unknown data type: "FK71CEE68EBA16946C"; SQL statement:
alter table Product_Category add index FK71CEE68EBA16946C (Product_productId), add constraint FK71CEE68EBA16946C foreign key (Product_productId) references Product (productId) [50004-171]
Hibernate: alter table Stock add index FK4C806F66E8438A (item_itemId), add constraint FK4C806F66E8438A foreign key (item_itemId) references Item (itemId)
Apr 30, 2013 9:18:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table Stock add index FK4C806F66E8438A (item_itemId), add constraint FK4C806F66E8438A foreign key (item_itemId) references Item (itemId)
Apr 30, 2013 9:18:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Unknown data type: "FK4C806F66E8438A"; SQL statement:
alter table Stock add index FK4C806F66E8438A (item_itemId), add constraint FK4C806F66E8438A foreign key (item_itemId) references Item (itemId) [50004-171]
Hibernate: alter table StockKeeper add index FKF22CD8887F68140 (itemWarehouseCatalog_itemWarehouseCatalogId), add constraint FKF22CD8887F68140 foreign key (itemWarehouseCatalog_itemWarehouseCatalogId) references ItemWarehouseCatalog (itemWarehouseCatalogId)
Apr 30, 2013 9:18:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table StockKeeper add index FKF22CD8887F68140 (itemWarehouseCatalog_itemWarehouseCatalogId), add constraint FKF22CD8887F68140 foreign key (itemWarehouseCatalog_itemWarehouseCatalogId) references ItemWarehouseCatalog (itemWarehouseCatalogId)
Apr 30, 2013 9:18:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport perform
ERROR: Unknown data type: "FKF22CD8887F68140"; SQL statement:
alter table StockKeeper add index FKF22CD8887F68140 (itemWarehouseCatalog_itemWarehouseCatalogId), add constraint FKF22CD8887F68140 foreign key (itemWarehouseCatalog_itemWarehouseCatalogId) references ItemWarehouseCatalog (itemWarehouseCatalogId) [50004-171]
Apr 30, 2013 9:18:42 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

What is causing the those `ERROR: Unknown data type: "FKF22CD8887F68140"; SQL statement:` errors?

**How can I achieve same environment using H2 as MySQL?**

Comment: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql] => Looks to me that spring is not able to find your schema.sql.Maybe this can help [answer about path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11111868/2115680)

Comment: Sorry, I did mistake, I don't want to run any scripts but a database. So, I removed `.addDefaultScripts()`. Another problem occurs, now H2 database don't allowing to define foreign key constraints.(`ERROR: Unknown data type: "FK4C806F66E8438A"; SQL statement:`)

Comment: Can you please edit the question with the new stacktrace and the code that has been modified ?

Comment: I've updated the question, After removing `.addDefaultScripts()`, the question is changed a bit.

Comment: Did you set the correct hibernate dialect? Else whats you persistence config?

Comment: I'll update question with all my application context config.

Comment: H2 is not 100% compatible with MySQL. I'm afraid in this case you will have to use the H2 dialect, because H2 doesn't support this particular SQL statement.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the following property in your hibernate configuration:

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

Also, change your datasource configuration to use the h2 configuration.

Comment: next time say what that h2 configuration is